# Yandex-maps api v 3.0 + React приложение

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Не понимаю как подключить api третьей версии к реакту.
В документации описывается подключение через 
Имеется react приложение, созданное через npx react-create-app. Обычно создаю компоненты через

```
const ProgressBar = () => {
return (
    <div>
    </div>
);
}
export default ProgressBar
```

И в App.js просто пишу

```
<ProgressBar />
```

Comment: Я немного не в теме, но... Вариант, предлагаемый самим Яндексом в качестве образца прям никак не подходит? https://codesandbox.io/s/yimzzd?file=/webpack.config.js

Comment: Хм, я вообще не пользовался вебпаком, надо посмотреть, что это такое. Но я думаю, что это не тот самый ответ на вопрос